# Some questions on Docker basics?

Tags: docker, devops, concourse

I'm new to docker.Most of the tutorials on docker cover the same thing.I'm afraid I'm just ending up with piles of questions,and no answers really. I've come here after my fair share of Googling, kindly help me out with these basic questions.

1. When we install a docker,where it gets installed? Is it in our computer in local or does it happen in cloud?
2. Where does containers get pulled into?I there a way I can see what is inside the container?(I'm using Ubuntu 18.04)
3. When we pull an image.Docker image or clone a repository from
   Git.where does this data get is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The docker daemon gets installed on your local machine and everything you do with the `docker` cli gets executed on your local machine and containers.
2. (not sure about the 1st part of your question). You can easily access your docker containers by `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash` for that you will need to have the container running. Check running containers with `docker ps`
3. (again I do not entirely understand your question) The images that you pull get stored on your local machine as well. You can see all the images present on your machine with `docker images`

Let me know if it was helpful and if you need any futher information.

Comment: @PPetkov.Thank you for answering.Yes I can see my docker images and containers.But in local where can I see what is inside the docker images?Can I even see it?For Ex:-created one concourse image.I can see the image size being 524MBs.But I can't see what is there inside it.

Comment: @lionxlamb you will need to run the image in a container `docker run image_name:tag_name` and then `exec` into it to check its contents. Its basically like ssh-ing into a remote server

Comment: you can also use `docker image inspect` but that shows overall information about the image https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_inspect/

Comment: awesome.I can see the details using `docker run image_name:tag_name` and <worker> incase of Concourse.I have one more question though.As I can see docker in my  `snap/docker` can container details be physically verified in system.Any path that can be used?

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'physically verified' but `docker stats` gives you a live stream of data for your containers

Comment: @PPetkov.I had this misinterpretation that container details can be seen(physically verified,as in,it can be seen your system,in a folder structure).But I've much better idea now.If container details could be accessible,then everything will be accessible to user.Using source codes and credentials.I know it was dumb of me not to have understood this before.Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are confused after reading to many documents. Let me try to put this in simple words. Hope this will help.

> When we install a docker,where it gets installed? Is it in our
>   computer in local or does it happen in cloud?

- We install the docker on VM be it you on-prem VM or cloud. You can install the docker on your laptop as well.

> Where does containers get pulled into?I there a way I can see what is
>   inside the container?(I'm using Ubuntu 18.04)

- This question can be treated as lack of terminology awareness. We don't pull the container. We pull the image and run the container using that.

  **Quick terminology summary**

  **Container**-> Containers allow you to easily package an application's code, configurations, and dependencies into a template called an image.

  **Dockerfile**-> Here you mention your commands or infrastructure blueprint.

  **Image** -> Image gets derived from Dockerfile. You use image to create and run the container.

  Yes, you can log inside the container. Use below command

  `docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash`

> When we pull an image.Docker image or clone a repository from
>   Git.where does this data get is stored?

- You can pull the opensource image from [Docker-hub](https://hub.docker.com/)
- When you clone the git project which is docerized, you can look for Dockerfile in that project and create the your own image by build it.

  `docker build -t <youimagenae:tag> .`
- When you build or pull the image it get store in to your local.

  user `docker images` command

**Refer the below cheat-sheet for more commands to play with docker.**
[image]

Comment: @Akshay.Thank you for helping.These commands are useful.And as you said I was absolutely confused after reading so many documents,which essentially teaches the same thing,but didn't clear my doubts.

Comment: @lionxlamb Any specific reason to unaccept this answer?

Comment: @Akshay.Your answer serves the same purpose as Ppetkov's and is more detailed.However I got my resolution from Ppetkov's answer and also he answered first.If I could, I would've accepted both the answers.Thank you for all the help,I really appreciate it.

Comment: @lionxlamb. Thanks for reply. Just wanted to check if this answer servers the purpose or not.

Comment: **Can someone please add some meaningful modification before down voting the answer.?**